# vertical oriented linetype legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using the following guide style:

```
guide.style <- guide_legend(keywidth=.1, keyheight=.5, direction = "horizontal",
                              title.position = "top",
                              label.position="bottom", label.hjust = 0.5, label.vjust = .5,
                              label.theme = element_text(angle = 90, size=8))
guides(color = guide.style, linetype = guide.style)
```

The legend for linetypes draws the lines horizontally across the grey squares. However, the whole point of this guide style is to use less width per legend entry to squeeze a lot of very tall entries into the legend.

[image: Illustration of problem]

Is there a way to draw the linetype legend vertically?

Comment: I don't see how having the lines vertical will help you squeeze more the legend: it seems to me that it's the interline spacing for the text labels that's the limiting factor. How about splitting the legend into several columns instead, and perhaps putting it at the top/bottom of the plot?

Comment: I have other plots with much longer category names. I want to use the full height for the category names. I agree that reducing the interline spacing might help a bit. If I could draw the linetype example vertically then I could reduce the side of the gray box even more.

Comment: Why not using the legend in the vertical position?